# Building a json dynamically in Python

Tags: python, json, slack

I am trying to build a JSON in Python. I want to send it to Slack.

```
xxdata = []
xxdata.append("Option A")
xxdata.append("Option B")
data=[]
for xx in xxdata:
    item = {"text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": xx,
                        "emoji": True
                    }}
    data.append(dict(item))
jsonData=json.dumps(data)
```

This is how I am sending it to slack:

```
        {
        "type": "section",
        "block_id": "Settings1",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": ":gear: *MAIN*\nSelect your main group"
        },
        "accessory": {
            "type": "static_select",
            "placeholder": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Option A",
                "emoji": True
            },
            "options": jsonData,
            "action_id": "NotificationSelect"
        }
```

However, when it is sent to Slack - I am getting additional quotation marks before and after the **option** data:

```
    {
     "type": "section", 
     "block_id": "Settings1", 
     "text": 
           {
               "type": "mrkdwn", 
               "text": ":gear: *MAIN*\nSelect your main group"}, 
     "accessory": {
               "type": "static_select",
               "placeholder": {
                       "type": "plain_text", 
                       "text": "Option A", 
                       "emoji": true}, 
     "options": "[
                 {
                  "text": 
                        {"type": "plain_text", 
                         "text": "Option A",  
                         "emoji": true}
                 },
                 {"text": 
                        {"type": "plain_text", 
                         "text": "Option B", 
                         "emoji": true}
                 }
  ]", 
       
 "action_id": "NotificationSelect"}},
```

This causing Slack to fail. what am I doing wrong?
If I am removing these quotation marks everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonData=json.dumps(data)` is making a string from your list. Just use `data` directly instead of `jsonData` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

JSON data is wrapped inside `""`. That is why you are having two quotation marks for the value of the `option` key.

Try skipping the step where you do:

```
jsonData=json.dumps(data)
```

As such, you will have this:

```
xxdata = []
xxdata.append("Option A")
xxdata.append("Option B")
data=[]
for xx in xxdata:
    item = {"text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": xx,
                        "emoji": True
                    }}
    data.append(dict(item))
```

Then:

```
    {
    "type": "section",
    "block_id": "Settings1",
    "text": {
        "type": "mrkdwn",
        "text": ":gear: *MAIN*\nSelect your main group"
    },
    "accessory": {
        "type": "static_select",
        "placeholder": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Option A",
            "emoji": True
        },
        "options": data,  # replace json with dict
        "action_id": "NotificationSelect"
    }
```